# How can I use channels to know when all goroutines started by a loop are completed

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm currently trying to `range` over a `map` to do concurrent database requests rather than synchronously, obviously because of the speed boost.

My problem is I have something like this:

```
var mainthreads = make(chan *mainthread)
var mainthreadsFetched = make(chan struct{})
for containerid := range containers {
    go func() {
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT thread_id, belongs_to, thread_name, access_level FROM forum_mainthread WHERE belongs_to = ?", containerid)
        defer rows.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        for rows.Next() {
            mainthread := &MainThread{}
            err := rows.Scan(&mainthread.MainThreadID, &mainthread.BelongsTo, &mainthread.ThreadName, &mainthread.AccessLevel)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            mainthreads <- mainthread
        }
    }()
    mainthreadsFetched <- struct{}{}
}

// Get all mainthreads
<-mainthreadsFetched
// Do other stuff after complete
```

Obviously `mainthreadsFetched <- struct{}{}` is being called almost instantly because the loop finishes faster than you can blink, how can I create a new channel per loop that will not block each new `goroutine` from starting, but rather let the loop start all `goroutines` and then send out on a channel when every `goroutine` is done.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sync.WaitGroup` is a great solution, and the one usually used.

Alternatively, you can receive on `mainthreadsFetched` `len(containers)` times, instead of just 1. That will guarantee that all go routines have completed. You'll need to move the send line to the end of the go routine (or, better, into a defer).

Also, since `containerid` is in the for loop, its value changes. You need to pass it as a parameter to the go routine closure.

Comment: OP explicitly said he knows he can use a `sync.WaitGroup` but is looking for an alternative using channels so you haven't really answered his question at all.

Comment: See the second paragraph of my answer were I give him such an alternative. I referenced `sync.WaitGroup` because it is the better solution, regardless of if he wants to use it or not.

Comment: @mjibson The only reason I don't want to use `sync.WaitGroup` is because I have a few nested database loops I'm going to end up having so I can get all relational database things, so I don't want `wg.Add(1)` and `wg.Done()` all over the place nested 15 times I thought channels were supposed to be a better solution

Comment: In either case I think you'll have to pass down a reference to either the channel or the wait group. Both of them equate to "run a function that tells something else to decrement the number of things it's waiting for".

Comment: Yeah good point. I think channels can work better than `WaitGroup` in scenarios like Datsik describes. However I need to think more to apply it here. The suggest mjibson made is alright, but it's relying on simple arithmetic to know it's done... I did an implementation more like you describe with a tree or lists of lists passing channels into every goroutine and then waiting for them to finish or be shutdown/aborted in a select nested in a for loop. I could possibly provide some kind of example but it's not gonna be right now.

Comment: @mjibson Sorry I left out 2 lines in the code, I added another channel to better describe what I was attempting to do

Comment: In either case the code gets complicated quickly. If you're doing serious work in these goroutines, you'll probably have to add an abort channel after finding that you can shut down your program. You have to have the data out channel so you have at least two now. The func run in a goroutine now needs a select so it can receive it's abort signal while sending on the out channel -- After thinking a little more I believe I allocated a slice of channels so they were paired 1 to 1 with the goroutines and ranged over that collection waiting for the goroutine to close or signal on another channel.

Answer (score 0):

So the best way I could come up with doing this is to use `sync.WaitGroup` and do something like this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mainThreadFetched = make(chan MainThread)
for containerid := range containers {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(containerid int64) {
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT thread_id, belongs_to, thread_name, access_level FROM forum_mainthread WHERE belongs_to = ?", containerid)
        defer rows.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        for rows.Next() {
            mainthread := MainThread{}
            err := rows.Scan(&mainthread.MainThreadID, &mainthread.BelongsTo, &mainthread.ThreadName, &mainthread.AccessLevel)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            mainThreadFetched <- mainthread
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(containerid)
}

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(mainThreadFetched)
}()

for mainthread := range mainThreadFetched {
    containers[mainthread.BelongsTo].MainThreads = append(containers[mainthread.BelongsTo].MainThreads, mainthread)
}

// Do other stuff
```

Now I can read from the `mainThreadFetched` channel and then when the `WaitGroup` is satisfied it will close the channel allowing the loop to end and continue on

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are reading mainthreads. If it's not a buffered channel, you would need to solve that some way or another. I'm going to provide a few solutions for solving it - None are more "correct" than the other - it just depends on your needs.

**Variant A**
This is the simplest solution but it presumes you have some other goroutine reading mainthreads (which may already be the case)

```
var mainthreads = make(chan *mainthread)
var mainthreadsFetched = make(chan struct{})
go somethingWhichReadsMainThreads()
for containerid := range containers {
    go func(containerid int) {
        // build query omitted for brevity
        for rows.Next() {
            // omitted for brevity
            mainthreads <- mainthread
        }
        mainthreadsFetched <- struct{}{}
    }(containerid)
}

for i := 0; i < len(containers); i++ {
    <-mainThreadsFetched
}
close(mainthreads)
// Do other stuff after complete
```

---

**Variant B**
This one uses the [select](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) statement to deal with reading the threads separate from the completion notifications without needing yet another goroutine.

```
var mainthreads = make(chan *mainthread)
var mainthreadsFetched = make(chan struct{})
for containerid := range containers {
    go func(containerid int) {
        // build query omitted for brevity
        for rows.Next() {
            // omitted for brevity
            mainthreads <- mainthread
        }
        mainthreadsFetched <- struct{}{}
    }(containerid)
}

numComplete := 0
readRunning := true
for readRunning {
    select {
    case thread := <-mainthreads:
        // do something with thread, like threads = append(threads, thread)
    case <-mainthreadsFetched:
        numFetched++
        if numFetched == len(containers) {
            readRunning = False
        }
    }
}
// Do other stuff after complete
```

---

**Variant C**
This one uses the fact that you aren't using the 'zero value' (nil) for passing real data, so you can use that as a signal value instead of a separate struct channel. It has the advantage that it is far less code, but it does feel like spooky action at a distance.

```
var mainthreads = make(chan *mainthread)
for containerid := range containers {
    go func(containerid int) {
        // build query omitted for brevity
        for rows.Next() {
            // omitted Scan for brevity
            mainthreads <- mainthread
        }
        mainthreads <- nil // nil signals to us we are done
    }(containerid)
}

numComplete := 0
for thread := range mainthreads {
    if thread != nil {
        // do something with thread, like threads = append(threads, thread)
    } else {
        numFetched++
        if numFetched == len(containers) {
            break
        }
    }
}
// Do other stuff after complete
```